# Usage of self inside instance methods in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I have a class like this

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def test(self):
        x = self.var + 2
        return x
```

And then I make a class like this

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def test(self):
        self.x = self.var + 2
        return self.x
```

I understand that I can use `self` to separate attribute values across various instances of this class. My question is, if I create many utility variables (like `x`) inside a method, should I always create them using `self`?

Can anyone explain how the above two classes behave differently (if they do)?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. `x` in the first example is not an attribute; it's just a local variable. Unless you need a value that persists across method calls, prefer the local variable.

Comment: If you're going to use the `x` value in more than one method, then it should be bound to `self` and this initial definition of `self.x` should be done in the `__init__` method

Comment: @JacobIRR I'll use it inside just one method.

Comment: Using `self` does not create a local variable. If you want a local variable, where the value goes away at the end of the method, then use a local variable (no `self`). If you want an instance attribute, where the value is retained on the instance after the method finishes, then use an instance attribute (with `self`).

Comment: in that case, no need to use `self.`

Comment: @kindall Thank you, that cleared it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the difference between the two classes :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def test(self):
        x = self.var + 2
        return x
```

Let's create a Test object:

```
t = Test(1)
```

And see what we can do

```
t.var # 1
t.x # Raises AttributeError : no such attribute in the class
t.test() #3
t.x # Still erroring
```

And with your second class

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
    def test(self):
        self.x = self.var + 2
        return self.x
```

Let's create a Test object:

```
t = Test(1)
```

And see what we can do

```
t.var # 1
t.x # Raises AttributeError : no such attribute in the class
t.test() #3
t.x # 3
```

So what ? Well we can see that any variables defined with `self.VARNAME` persist in the instance, while simple local variables, without `self.`, dosen't.

However, if x needs to be accessible with t.x, i'd probably go for a property, like so

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    @property
    def x(self):
        x = self.var + 2
        return x

t = Test() 
t.x # 3
```